# How to convert a set of probabilities to 0 and 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have given a dataset that contains two columns 'y' and 'proba'. 'y' has two class labels '0' and '1' and 'proba' is the probability.

I have to create a list 'y_hat' If my 'proba' < 0.5 then I append 0 else 1. I have written the code:

```
y_hat = [0 if (df_5a['proba']<0.5) else 1]
```

However, I'm getting the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
(df['proba'] >= .5).astype(int)
```

or

```
df['proba'].ge(.5).astype(int)
```

Comment: I think the best solution here.

Answer (score 0):

```
y_hat = list(map(lambda x: 0 if x else 1, (df_5a['proba']<0.5).values))
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataset looks like this:

```
data= {'y':[0,0,1,0,1,0],
    'proba': [0.2,0.3,0.25,0.8,0.9,0.15]}

df_5a= pd.DataFrame(data)
df_5a
```

Output:

```
    y   proba
0   0   0.20
1   0   0.30
2   1   0.25
3   0   0.80
4   1   0.90
5   0   0.15
```

your code does not work because, as the error indicates, it is *ambiguous* in terms of what you are specifically checking.

For instance, if you only wanted to apply your condition to the 1st row (`['proba'][0]`), then by adding its index your code would work fine:

```
y_hat = [0 if (df_5a['proba'][0] <0.5) else 1]
y_hat
```

Output:

```
[0]
```

Hence, although I find the answer of @Gopal Gautam right, below is my suggestion from another approach using [pandas.DataFrame.itertuples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html), through which you can iterate over each row:

```
y_hat=[]
for row in df_5a.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
  if row.proba < 0.5:
    y_hat.append(0)
  else:
    y_hat.append(1)

print(y_hat)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```